# Odd File Association Handling Bug

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xaml, windows-runtime

I have this in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Window.Current.Content = new Frame();
    ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args);
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

This in `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    FileActivatedEventArgs filesArgs = (FileActivatedEventArgs)e.Parameter;
    StorageFile file = (StorageFile)filesArgs.Files[0];
    mc.SetSource(await file.OpenReadAsync(), file.ContentType);
    mc.Play();
}
```

And this in `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mc" />
```

Now, I am facing a very odd problem. I have associated my app with .MP4 files. Whenever, I open any file, it doesn't get played immediately. For eg.

1. I open `a.mp4`, it doesn't get played and I don't close the app.
2. I open `b.mp4`, it doesn't get played and I don't close the app.
3. Then, I open `a.mp4`, it gets played. If it doesn't, I try again and it gets played. Now if I open any MP4 file, it gets played without any problems until I close the app.

So, this workaround works sometimes:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    FileActivatedEventArgs filesArgs = (FileActivatedEventArgs)e.Parameter;
    StorageFile file = (StorageFile)filesArgs.Files[0];
    StorageFile file2 = (StorageFile)filesArgs.Files[0];
    mc.SetSource(await file2.OpenReadAsync(), file2.ContentType);
    mc.SetSource(await file2.OpenReadAsync(), file2.ContentType);
    mc.Play();
}
```

Does anyone know why it is not working without the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the file doesn't play if you set the source and start playing to early, before the control is intialized and/or completely loaded. That's the reason why it works on subsequent calls when the app is already loaded and occasionally even on the first call. I made a simple app and managed to reproduce your problem most of the tries (although sometimes it worked).

I tried a simple workaround to always wait for the `MediaElement` to get loaded before I started playing and it seems that the problem is gone - I couldn't reproduce it in more than a dozen calls.

Here's what I've done:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mc" Loaded="mc_Loaded" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
bool loaded = false;
Task task = new Task(() => {});

private void mc_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loaded = true;
    task.Start();
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    FileActivatedEventArgs filesArgs = (FileActivatedEventArgs)e.Parameter;
    StorageFile file = (StorageFile)filesArgs.Files[0];
    if (!loaded)
        await task;
    mc.SetSource(await file.OpenReadAsync(), file.ContentType);
    mc.Play();
}
```

I don't really like my solution because it's only based on guessing and empirical testing, but I couldn't find any documentation stating what needs to happen to `MediaElement` before it's ready.

Comment: @Programmer I was testing it on Core 2 Duo 6400.

Comment: @Programmer If you're using `FilePicker` by calling it from a page on which the `MediaElement` is placed, I don't think the same situation can occur. `MediaElement` gets loaded during the load process of the page, the page is already loaded when you open the `FilePicker`. It might be a bug or at least an un(der)documented feature. You could try posting the problem on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp), there more people from Microsoft present there. Or maybe even on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: @Programmer Have you tried using the `MediaOpened` event as suggested? Does it solve your problem?